# c# using a binding source to add row to an sql table with incremental identity field

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, dataset, bindingsource

I have a program I created in Visual studio. The program is basically a place for everyone to store passwords for company and external accounts. I want to further this application by automatically creating the company accounts when I create a new user. I approached this by using the binding source. I can get the row into the database but it doesn't use the sql supplied auto increment. I will post the code but I am trying to figure out if I went about this the wrong way. I am not 100% familiar with how the connector and classes that visual studio create when you connect the solution to the database. I am not looking for code to help me do this I am looking for explanations and guidance. If responding with code please help me understand by explaining the code.

```
            DataSet.AccountsRow newdomainuserrow = DBDataSet.Accounts.NewAccountsRow();

            newdomainuserrow.USer = userIDTextBox.Text.ToString();
            newdomainuserrow.UserName = userIDTextBox.Text.ToString();

            System.DateTime moment = new DateTime();
            newdomainuserrow.Password = moment.Year;
            newdomainuserrow.AccountName = "Domain";
            drawingNumDBDataSet.Accounts.Rows.Add(newdomainuserrow);
            MessageBox.Show("User Saved");

            this.Validate();
            this.usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.accountBindingSource.Endedit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.DataSet);
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Matt

Comment: Which database field is being auto incremented, and what do you mean when you say that "it doesn't use the sql supplied auto increment?"  Generally, when you insert a row into sql, the identity column (ID) will be assigned automatically.  Your C# program will have no knowledge of what ID was assigned unless you request that from the database (usually using SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the last identity created within the transaction scope).  This may be done for you automatically (behind the scenes) based on the way you are binding the rows - what is the specific problem that you are running into?

Comment: Pretty very difficult to understand what your problem is. Tip: Dump those "connectors" and write the SQL code yourself, it will help you on the long run understanding how your database operates. Also, make sure SQL (Server?) is the right database for your task. Storing account data for a few hundred users could be done with things as trivial as an encrypted text file (not recommending it though), and would be much easier for you. There are many database implementations out there that are much "easier" to use than SQL (try CouchDB).

Comment: Well if I bind text boxes to the dataset. I simply call dataset add new user populates the text boxes and the update will get the next increment number automatically. The problem is I want to set field values without binding to a text box just simply like you see row.column=value. I don't think you can do that with a dataset. So I figured using the bindingsource was the way to go but i can't get it to insert and let sql do its thing. The field is called identity that is set to increment 1 at a time. I am sorry if this doesn't make sense I am slowly learning all of this.

Comment: It's OK, but "I can't get it to insert and let sql do its thing," is not very specific so it's difficult to guess at all the possible things that can go wrong.  When you try to insert, does the program crash?  If so what is the error message?  Does the program keep running but no row gets inserted into the DB?  Does it successfully insert a row but the "identity" column is null?  Does it successfully insert a row and generate an ID, but your DataSet doesn't update properly until you restart the program?

Comment: The program crashes. It reads column "identity" cannot be null. If I give it a random number it will allow the program to run to completion and give the identity the random number I gave it. The problem is I just want it to save the information and let sql assign the identity number. Is using a binding source the way to do this? Like I said with the dataset addnew I bind to textboxes it works but I don't want user input I want to set them based on parameters gathered elsewhere. Can this be accomplished with a dataset and not bind to text boxes or datagridview?

Comment: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx) this is what I am trying to do but I get the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The id field is not longer an identity autoincrement field. To increment the id field one by one programmatically like I need to I wrote a simply while statement to get all numbers that were not used. This works if there is a deleted row it will insert one where there is one missing. here is the code I used.

```
            Boolean gotnum;                
            gotnum = false;
            int idnum = 1;

            while  (gotnum != true)
            {
                DrawingNumDBDataSet.AccountsRow actrw = drawingNumDBDataSet.Accounts.FindById(idnum);
                idnum++;
                if (actrw==null)
                {

                    gotnum = true;
                    idnum--;
                }


            }
```

I then set the Id field = to idnum. This is probably not the best practice but it is the best I could come up with.